# Getting error while uploading multiple images with multipart form data in Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire, multipartform-data

I've searched many questions and applied solutions but somehow my logic is not working properly. This is what is expected in the API call:

[image]

And the call which I'm sending is:

```
let parameters = [
                "address": self.addressField.text ?? "",
                "pharmacy_id": "\(pharmaID ?? 0)",
                "is_default": "\(isDefault ?? 0)",
                "cash_payment": "\(1)",
                "is_home_delivery": "\(isDelivery ?? 0)"
                ] as [String : Any]

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in

                for key in parameters.keys {
                    let name = String(key)
                    if let val = parameters[name] as? String{
                        multipartFormData.append(val.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: name)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                for (image) in self.presImagesArray {
                    if  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
                        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "prescription[]", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    }
                }

//                     for (image) in self.presImagesArray {
//                    multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)!, withName: "prescription", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
//                    }

                }
            },
                             usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                             to:url,
                             method:.post,
                             headers:headers,
                             encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                                switch encodingResult {
                                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                    upload.responseJSON { response in
//                                        if let result = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
//                                            print(result["message"])
//                                        }
                                        print(response)
                                        self.clearAllNotice()
                                        self.successNotice("Success")
                                    }
                                case .failure(let encodingError):
                                    print(encodingError, encodingError.localizedDescription)
                                    self.clearAllNotice()
                                    self.errorNotice(encodingError.localizedDescription)
                                }
            })
        } else {
            self.noticeInfo("Login Needed")
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that the call returns with a message that `The prescription field is required.` which means the uploading images in `prescription[]` is not working properly and the backend guys are saying that the problem is at my end.

As you can see from code I've added a `for` loop and inside of it I'm converting and sending the image data and the key is `prescription[]` but still I'm getting this response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` to create the images. The caller of this closure continues as soon as you leave this method, so since you're adding the images asynchronously, the parameters have already been sent before the images can be added.

If you really need to call a different queue, you would instead need to use `DispatchQueue.main.sync` in order to block the closure until the dispatch completes. However, you don't need this, and it's also not recommended that you perform `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` on the main/UI thread as it's a heavy function and you'll be blocking the UI.